# How to edit a table cell using a form

Tags: javascript, html-table

Hello I would really love to use some help here, I have this homework where i need to click on add,edit, delete buttons on a table: I GOT THE ADD AND DELETE ONES FIGURED OUT.But i'm stuck on the edit one, so I have to click on the edit button in the last cell the edit button would display a form in that form the cell information should appear and i need to be able to mofidy them. here is the html code of the form:

```
<!--edit form-->
<form id="editform" style="display: none;">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Informations du joueur</legend>
      <label>Nom: <input name="Name" /></label>
      <label>
        Palmares :
        <textarea name="address" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
      </label>
  <input type="button" value="Soumettre" onclick="Soumettre2()">
  <input type="button" value="Annuler" onclick="Cancel()" >
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

the first button ( Soumetter2 () function ) is where i have the problem, i didnt share the table html because it has a lot of information in it but its just a basic html table. Thanks for any help in advance

I tried some google ressources but nothing like I want. i shouldnt use jquery

Comment: Please refer this: https://codeinhouse.com/edit-selected-row-using-javascript/

Comment: Hello your code has helped me so much, I finally could do it thank you very much. i have just one question left, because in my table theres the add new row button (the add button isnt on the table its outside the table) so when i add new rows the modify button doesnt work on them i tried this :  Modifier.setAttribute('onclick', 'Modifier(this)'); so here i set an attribute to the button i added dynamically but in your code for the elements that are already in the table the onclick function is modifier(this,1) or modifier (this, 2) theres a number with this, what do i do about it ? thank you

Comment: Add an class attribute to the td elements holding the anchor element and then add this code inside that add function: var counter = document.querySelectorAll('.customclass').length;  var newcount = counter+1; You will get the count of elements in counter variable. And when you add another row into the table you can use the newcount variable for the number you said in the onclick attribute.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for answering, i might not have completely understood you because im a little new to javascript, so when you said to "Add an class attribute to the td elements holding the anchor element" I didnt understand this part, but i did the rest a bit as you said , heres what i did i added this to my add function : var counter = document.querySelectorAll('td').length; var newcount = counter+1; im not sure the td inside queryselectorall is the right thing to do , then for the last part i added Modify.setAttribute('onclick', 'Modify(this,newcount)');

Comment: im sorry i dont exactly know what im doing , it didnt work , i really hope for just a bit more clarified answer from you, you really helped me a lot and I appreciate it

Comment: I was referring to this td element in the html. <td>
                <a onclick="toggleModal(this, 1)">Edit</a>
                <a onclick="removeRow(this)">Delete</a>
            </td> So when you add class attribute to it, the td element starting tag will be like this: <td class="customclass">

Comment: Hello thank you for answering again, heres what i did :

Comment: i gave a class to the td holding the buttons in my table like this: (im not sure if you said to only give it to the first td that holds the buttons or them all, so i tried both , both didnt work for me but heres it

Comment: <td class="customclass">
        <input type="button" value="Modifier" onclick="modify(this,10)" >
        <input type="button" value="Supprimer" onclick="delete(this)">
      </td> I gave it to all of them

Comment: then i added this to my add function as you said  var counter = document.querySelectorAll('.customclass').length; var newcount = counter+1 then i gave the modify button i created this Modifybtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'Modify(this,newcount)');

Comment: but then i tried modifying a new row in my html page in the browser but nothing happens

Comment: i dont know what im doing wrong i would appreciate it if you guide me

Comment: Please refer this: https://codepen.io/robyrajuoommen/pen/YzvRNPK

Comment: thank you soo much kind sir it finally works, I appreciate your help so much I wish you nothing but the best in your life